# Wired connection totally disappeared from the settings

Tags: networking, connection, router, wired

My pc is connected to the router which provides connection data automatically [ip,dns and all other]

I have dual boot in my pc, windows and ubuntu, The wired connection works fine in Windows, but no wired connection exists in ubuntu.
I had used the same wired connection without applying any change before. But now the wired connection options doesn't exist as if it not connected at all.
How do I solve that?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `uname -r`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema, never mind, I have reinstalled and the problem is solved. Thanks anyway